# Output message if combined 'dice value' is found inside an array

Tags: javascript

If you've ever played craps, some of these numbers might look familiar.
I'm just starting out with Javascript so it probably shows. Here's where I'm at

This logic assumes a 10 count roll. Starting with iteration number 1, if the combined value of 'myRoll' is found inside the 'point' array, that first found number needs to be the established 'point' (pointNumber).

For example, (if 'myRoll' === 6) then 6 should be the 'pointNumber'.

I want to output the message 'Frontline winner!' if the first 'pointNumber' (in this case, 6)
gets randomly chosen again.

```js
const point = [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]

let pointNumber = 0
const n = 10

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  let dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  let dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  let myRoll = dice1 + dice2

  if (point.includes(myRoll)) {
    pointNumber = myRoll
  }
  console.log('Roll:' + i + ' Dice: ' + myRoll + ' Point:' + pointNumber)
}
```

This what the output currently looks like:

Roll:1 Dice: 6 Point:6

Roll:2 Dice: 9 Point:9

Roll:3 Dice: 10 Point:10

Roll:4 Dice: 10 Point:10

Roll:5 Dice: 6 Point:6

Roll:6 Dice: 5 Point:5

Roll:7 Dice: 6 Point:6

Roll:8 Dice: 7 Point:6

Roll:9 Dice: 8 Point:8

Roll:10 Dice: 11 Point:8

Here is how it should be displayed:

Roll:1 Dice: 6 Point:6

Roll:2 Dice: 9 Point:6

Roll:3 Dice: 10 Point:6

Roll:4 Dice: 10 Point:6

Roll:5 Dice: 6 Frontline winner!

Roll:6 Dice: 5 Point:5

Roll:7 Dice: 6 Point:5

Roll:8 Dice: 7 seven out

Roll:9 Dice: 8 Point:8

Roll:10 Dice: 11 Point:8

Notice how the 'dice' matched the 'point' on roll 5, resulting in a "Frontline winner"
And on the next role the 'point' is re-established again, until it is met (or a 7 is dealt).

This is just a fun personal exercise I am working on. Any help would be great!

**UPDATE** Okay, I got the logic to work exactly how it should. Some of the wording needs to be tweaked to be more cohesive with craps terminology and I'm sure there are many ways to improve this code, but at least it's a start:

```
  //const { point, craps, come_out, bigRed, Yo } = require('./checkRoll')

  const point = [4,5,6,8,9,10]

  let NonpointNumberArr = []
  let pointNumberArr = []
  let pointNumber = 0
  const n = 10
  let isPointWinner = false
  let isSeven = false

  for (let i=1; i<= n; i++) {
      let text = [`Roll: ${i}`]
      let dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      let dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      let myRoll = []
      myRoll[i] = dice1 + dice2
      text.push(`Dice: ${myRoll[i]}`)

      if(myRoll[i] === 7) {
          text.push(`seven out`)
          isSeven = true
          isPointWinner = false
          NonpointNumberArr.push(myRoll[i])
          pointNumber = 0
          pointNumberArr = []
      } else {
        
      if (!point.includes(myRoll[i])){
          isPointWinner = false
          text.push(`Point: ${pointNumber}`)
          NonpointNumberArr.push(myRoll[i])
      }}  
      
      if (point.includes(myRoll[i])){
          pointNumberArr.push(myRoll[i])
          if (myRoll[i] === pointNumber) {
              text.push(`frontline winner!`)
              pointNumber = 0
              pointNumberArr = []
          } else {
              pointNumber = pointNumberArr[0]
              text.push(`Point: ${pointNumber}`)
          }
      }

     isSeven = false
     console.log(text.join(' '))

     }

  //  console.log(`\npoint number ${pointNumber}`)
  //  console.log(`\npoint numbers: ${pointNumberArr}`)
  //  console.log(`\nNon point numbers: ${NonpointNumberArr}`)
```

Comment: So the first thing you need to do is check if `myRoll` is equal to `pointNumber` at the right time? Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: Hi @Ry, that's what I'm trying to figure out. I'm just not sure where to place that logic.

Comment: Not very optimum. For example `let myRoll = []; myRoll[i] = dice1 + dice2` does not make sense. You should move `let myRoll =[];` outside the loop, and clear it when necessary

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
const point = [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
let pointNumber = 0, n = 10, pointArr = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  let text = [`Roll: ${i}`]
  let dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  let dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  let myRoll = dice1 + dice2
  text.push(`Dice: ${myRoll}`)
  if (myRoll === 7) {
    pointArr = [];
    text.push(`seven out`)
  } else {
    if (point.includes(myRoll)) {
      pointNumber = myRoll;
      text.push(`Point: ${pointNumber}`)
      if (pointArr.includes(pointNumber)) text.push(`Frontline winner!`)
      pointArr.push(myRoll);
    }
    else text.push(`Point: 0`)
  }
  console.log(text.join(' '))
}
```

Comment: Why did a straightforward for loop get converted into `Array.from({ length: 10 }).forEach((_,i) => {`?

Comment: I'll tinker around with this, but the output on my first run looks like this:
Roll: 1 Dice: 7 Point: 0
Roll: 2 Dice: 10 Point: 10
Roll: 3 Dice: 8 Point: 8
Roll: 4 Dice: 8 Point: 8 Frontline winner!
Roll: 5 Dice: 5 Point: 5
Roll: 6 Dice: 6 Point: 6
Roll: 7 Dice: 6 Point: 6 Frontline winner!
Roll: 8 Dice: 10 Point: 10 Frontline winner!
Roll: 9 Dice: 2 Point: 10 Frontline winner!
Roll: 10 Dice: 9 Point: 9

No quite there but I do appreciate the suggestions

Comment: @Ry- Ok, converted it back - i is not even used.

Comment: @Derek what is expected outcome on subsequent rolls? Only ONE frontline winner in 10 throws?

Comment: Here I reset the array when I get a 7.

Comment: Hi @mplungjan - there could definitely be more than one frontline winner in 10 rolls, but there could also be zero. That's craps gambling for you. I tested your modified code and we're pretty close. Thank you by the way!

Comment: @mplungjan here is the output of the 10 rolls:

Roll: 1 Dice: 11 Point: 0
Roll: 2 Dice: 8 Point: 8
Roll: 3 Dice: 8 Point: 8 Frontline winner! 
Roll: 4 Dice: 4 Point: 4
Roll: 5 Dice: 6 Point: 6
Roll: 6 Dice: 4 Point: 4 Frontline winner! 
Roll: 7 Dice: 7 seven out
Roll: 8 Dice: 9 Point: 9
Roll: 9 Dice: 5 Point: 5
Roll: 10 Dice: 5 Point: 5 Frontline winner!

Roll 5 should still be 'point: 4'
Roll 9 should be 'point: 9'
Roll 10 should still be point 9 and not a front line winner.

I'll mess around with this later today. Thank you again.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps#Rules_of_play

Answer (score 0):

```
  const point = [4,5,6,8,9,10]
  let pointNumberArr = []
  let myRoll = []
  let pointNumber = 0
  const n = 10

  for (let i=1; i<= n; i++) {
      let text = [`Roll: ${i}`]
      let dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      let dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

      myRoll[i] = dice1 + dice2
      text.push(`Dice: ${myRoll[i]}`)

      if(myRoll[i] === 7) {
          text.push(`seven out`)
          pointNumber = 0
          pointNumberArr = []
      } else {
  
      if (!point.includes(myRoll[i])){
          text.push(`Point: ${pointNumber}`)
      }}  

       if (point.includes(myRoll[i])){
          pointNumberArr.push(myRoll[i])
           if (myRoll[i] === pointNumber) {
               text.push(`frontline winner!`)
               pointNumber = 0
               pointNumberArr = []
           } else {
              pointNumber = pointNumberArr[0]
              text.push(`Point: ${pointNumber}`)
          }
      }
      console.log(text.join(' '))
     }
```